# I want to update the values but i dont want to change image when i update image is remove

Tags: php

I am updating my form values . Image is already uploaded and can see on the form. When i only update the text value the image is remove and it showing blank.means it does not remains the same when i update it just remove automatically i think not getting the path for current image value when i updating other values. kindly help me to sort out this problem
like if i have to update only name of the person i change the name and other fields remains same. When i click on update all values remains same and also update one which i update but problem is this photo is remove not remain same

```
<?php

$v_id = $_GET['v_id'];
include "config.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_veh_ven WHERE v_id='$v_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  ?>
        <!-- form start -->
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="updateVehicle.php?v_id=<?= $row["v_id"] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="box-body">


            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
              <label for="">25+ Days Rent in PKR</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="v_25_plus_rent" value="<?=$row["v_25_plus_rent"]?>">
            </div>



            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-0 col-md-8">
              <label >Change Vehicle Picture</label>
              <input  type="file"  name="image" id="myFile" value="images/<?=$row["image"]?>" accept="image/*">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-0 col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
              <label for="exampleInputFile" style="text-align: center;" >Current Vehicle Picture</label>
              <?php echo'<Image src="images/'.$row["image"].'" style="width:325px;height:220px;"></Image>'; ?>
            </div>

            <div class=" ">
              <div class=" with-border" style="text-align:center;">
                <h4 class="box-title" style="text-align:center;"><b>Vendor Details</b></h4>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer skin-yellow">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary skin-yellow">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }

 } else {
    echo "Sorry something wrong";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

## updating file

```
   <?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  { 

   $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $v_type = $_POST["v_type"];
   $v_name = $_POST["v_name"];
   $v_man = $_POST["v_man"];
   $v_model = $_POST["v_model"];
   $v_color = $_POST["v_color"];
   $v_trans = $_POST["v_trans"];
   $v_1_15_rent = $_POST["v_1_15_rent"];
   $v_16_25_rent = $_POST["v_16_25_rent"];
   $v_25_plus_rent = $_POST["v_25_plus_rent"];
   $v_reg = $_POST["v_reg"];
   $vendor_name = $_POST["vendor_name"];
   $vendor_mobile = $_POST["vendor_mobile"];
   $vendor_price = $_POST["vendor_price"];
   $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
   $v_id=$_GET["v_id"];

   $sql = " UPDATE my_veh_ven SET v_type='$v_type', v_name='$v_name' ,v_man='$v_man' ,v_color='$v_color', v_trans='$v_trans',  v_1_15_rent='$v_1_15_rent' , v_16_25_rent='$v_16_25_rent' ,v_25_plus_rent='$v_25_plus_rent' , image='$image' , v_reg='$v_reg' ,vendor_name='$vendor_name', vendor_mobile='$vendor_mobile' ,vendor_price='$vendor_price'  WHERE v_id='$v_id' ";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    {

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))
                {
                $success = "✓ Successfully Updated";
                }

   }
  else
   {
                $fail = "X  Not Updated";
   }
   }

    mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
```

Comment: I don't think anybody will be able to help you, there's simply not enough information in the question. For instance; How do you 'update the text value'? For more information see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it seems that when you submit the form the empty value store in database(if you are adding image name in db and upload image in folder structure)

Comment: I have update the code. I want only change the rent value. I want image remains same . But when i update image is path is empty so there is no image .

Comment: please paste `updateVehicle.php` files code

Comment: Where is your code, from where you are updating your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<input type="file"/>` has no value attribute usage. The image, once uploaded, is on your server and that's about it. You cannot set the value of the input to anything that would be meaningful.

What you certainly want is to display the uploaded picture instead of the input, and present the input if the user wants to change it.

EDIT: Now that we have your PHP code, we can see that you are overwriting the $image variable even if empty

```
$image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

You have to verify if $_FILES["image"] exists, else image will be null or undefined. And then you will update the database with a bad value. I suggest you treat your upload differently than other data:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  { 

   $target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $v_type = $_POST["v_type"];
   $v_name = $_POST["v_name"];
   $v_man = $_POST["v_man"];
   $v_model = $_POST["v_model"];
   $v_color = $_POST["v_color"];
   $v_trans = $_POST["v_trans"];
   $v_1_15_rent = $_POST["v_1_15_rent"];
   $v_16_25_rent = $_POST["v_16_25_rent"];
   $v_25_plus_rent = $_POST["v_25_plus_rent"];
   $v_reg = $_POST["v_reg"];
   $vendor_name = $_POST["vendor_name"];
   $vendor_mobile = $_POST["vendor_mobile"];
   $vendor_price = $_POST["vendor_price"];

   $v_id=$_GET["v_id"];

   $sql = " UPDATE my_veh_ven SET v_type='$v_type', v_name='$v_name' ,v_man='$v_man' ,v_color='$v_color', v_trans='$v_trans',  v_1_15_rent='$v_1_15_rent' , v_16_25_rent='$v_16_25_rent' ,v_25_plus_rent='$v_25_plus_rent' , v_reg='$v_reg' ,vendor_name='$vendor_name', vendor_mobile='$vendor_mobile' ,vendor_price='$vendor_price'  WHERE v_id='$v_id' ";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    {

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))
                {
                $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
                $success = "✓ Successfully Updated";
                $sql = "UPDATE my_veh_ven SET image='$image' WHERE v_id='$v_id' ";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
                }

   }
  else
   {
                $fail = "X  Not Updated";
   }
   }

    mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
```

Comment: I want to image is not change means remains same as already uploaded to server and only want to update the text values. Along with text values image is also remove as when i update text value i not select any image as it is already on the server then image was broken and not showing

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: image in C:\xampp1\htdocs\carent.pk\admin\updatingveh.php on line 23

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution while adding put your image name in 1 hidden variable like below

```
$hiddenImage = $row["image"]
```

add this hidden variable in your form

```
<input type='hidden' name='hiddenImage' value='<?php echo $hiddenImage ?>'
```

and while submit check whether your file input type will contain any data or not. If data/image exist upload this image in folder and same name in db. if image not exist get that input variable save in database.

for e.g :

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) && $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] != "") {
// upload file and save image name in variable like $imagename 
}else{
// if image not upload this code will execute
$imagename = $_POST['hiddenImage'];
}
```

Save this `$imagename` variable data in database

Comment: if i want to update the image also then what should i do?

Comment: i have store image variable in db for images

Comment: At that time if condition run automatically

Comment: Thankyou Narayan Brother

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple solution for your problem. Whenever a form submits, check if $_FILES is set/any file is provided or not. If any file/image is provided, then update your database according to it. If the $_FILES array is empty, that means your image/file is not uploaded, and hence you can update it accordingly.

Something like below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //check for files or updated variables
    if(isset($_FILES)){
        //image is provided, now update values accrodingly in your database
        echo "image/file provided";
    }else{
        //image is not uploaded, update other values in database expect image/file
        echo "image/file not provided";
    }

}else{
    ?>
    <html>
        <head><title>My demo form</title></head>
        <body>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="data_one">
            <input type="file" name="my_file" accept="image/*">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```